# Reduce power formula/ convergence /simplify

Tags: convergence-divergence

I can't seem to be able to simplify this

$$x=(1-2*10^{-23})^{(2*10^{22})}$$

analytically, but it appears to converge to $x = \exp(-.4)$

(The exponent has an exponent.)

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\exp(a)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac an\right)^n$$
Your expression is of this form with $n=2\cdot 10^{22}, a=-.4$.  As your $n$ is "not too different from infinity" the value should be very close to $\exp(-.4)$ but [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2*10%5E-23%29%5E%282*10%5E22%29) gets fooled and returns $1$.